# MS Access, Use HTML in Web Browser Control to Open MS Access Form in Same MS Access file

Tags: vba, ms-access, webbrowser-control

OK, this one's a doozy. I've done some internet searches and not found any articles, forum questions or answers anywhere near it.

What I would like to do is open a Microsoft Access form from the HTML in a web browser control in the same Microsoft Access application.

The web browser control is being used to produce more predictable viewable output than trying to do something with continuous forms. This is fine for read-only output, and I don't expect to be able to edit the data in the control. However, it would be very useful to be able to write into the HTML being inserted into the control, a way to open one of the forms already in the MS Access file that the web control is in.

TIA, as always.

Comment: You are mixing different technologies. Access forms can only be opened in Access and a web browser cannot load/show a local access database.

Comment: You want to have code in HTML page displayed in WebBrowser control that will open a form normally within Access? I am not aware of any HTML code that can do that. Access VBA command to open form is DoCmd.OpenForm - I doubt VBA code can be embedded within HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to have a WebBrowser control with buttons in the HTML, where clicking the buttons causes VBA code to execute. That code could then open a form.

Set the control's Control Source to `="about:blank"`.

In the code behind the form, assuming the control is named `WBControl` do this:

```
Dim WBDocument As HTMLDocument
Dim WBBody As HTMLBody
Dim WithEvents Button_1 As HTMLButtonElement
Dim WithEvents Button_2 As HTMLButtonElement

Private Sub WBControl_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
If pDisp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE Then
    Set WBDocument = pDisp.Document
    Set WBBody = WBDocument.body
    WBBody.innerHTML = "Choose between <button id=btn-1>Click Me!</button>" & _
                       " and <button id=btn-2>No, Click Me!!</button>"
    Set Button_1 = WBDocument.getElementById("btn-1")
    Set Button_2 = WBDocument.getElementById("btn-2")
End If
End Sub

Private Function Button_1_onclick() As Boolean
Debug.Print "User clicked the first button."
End Function

Private Function Button_2_onclick() As Boolean
Debug.Print "User clicked the second button."
End Function
```

Rather than attaching event handlers to individual elements, I usually use

```
Dim WithEvents WBBody As HTMLBody
```

and then examine the clicked element to see what to do next:

```
Sub WBBody_onmousedown()
Dim ev As IHTMLEventObj
Dim el As HTMLObjectElement
Set ev = WBDocument.parentWindow.event
Set el = ev.srcElement
Debug.Print "User clicked a <"; el.tagName; "> element with id="; el.ID
End Sub
```

If the element clicked contains sub-elements that are not of interest, you can use `el.parentElement` to move up the DOM tree, looking for elements you want to treat as clickable. For example, responding to clicks over table cells, regardless of the complexity of the cell's contents.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will need to test it, but it's a work thing so that won't get done until next week now.